# how to update the remote repo if I modify, add and delete files in local working directory?

Tags: git

when I modify or add files in local working directory, I can following these 3 steps to update the remote repo

```
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push
```

if I delete file(s) in local working directory, for the first step I need to use `git rm file_name` instead of `git add`

then how about if I not only add some files but also delete some other files at the same time? what steps should I follow?

Comment: It works the same way. A single commit can include additions, deletions, and modifications. So what exactly is your question?

Comment: @EdCottrell if I delete a file and use `git add .`, then the remote repo won't change. what single commit can include addition/deletion and modification?

Comment: Well, don't use `git add .` to add a single file; that adds the entire current working directory (that's what the `.` means, after all). That would cancel out your `git rm file_name`. Use `git add yourFileName`. And keep in mind that `add`, `rm`, etc. never change the remote repository. Only committing and pushing your changes will change the remote repository.

Comment: @EdCottrell I know commit and push are needed to update the remote repo. What I mean is for the first step, "if I add some files and also delete some files, also I modify some files", what command should I use? git add is for adding files, git rm is for removing files.

Comment: I already explained that. Add the files you want to add, delete the ones you want to delete, and modify the ones you want to modify. Just don't add or delete the entire directory if that's not what you want to do.

Comment: Take a look at my answer below. Nonetheless I agree with @EdCottrell, explicitly staging changes is better practice than staging everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add all modifications, added files and deleted files to the tracked files to be committed use `git add -A`
then you can use `git commit` as you always do.

Comment: is `--all` equal to `-A`?

Comment: Yes, it is the same. You can always run `git help add` and see the full official help.